# Global function is not defined

Tags: python, global

I am facing this error as I define my module. I am trying to write a program for edit distance problem via dynamic programming method.

Here is the module where I am stuck:

```
def cost(i,j,M,w,text,pattern,compare): #Defining the cost functions or can say recurrence formula
    M[0,j]=0
    text1=list(text)
    pattern1=list(pattern)

    for i in range(1,m+1):
        for j in range(1,n+1):
            insertions = M[i-1,j]+1
            deletions = M[i,j-1]+1
            matches=M[i-1,j-1]


    if text1[i]==patttern1[j]:
        matches = matches+1
        return matches
    else :
        return matches
```

and the error is :

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Users/sayaneshome/Documents/plschk.py", line 202, in 
>     fill(M, w, text, max) #Filling matrix M with scores   File
>   "/Users/sayaneshome/Documents/plschk.py", line 117, in fill   c =
>   cost(i,j,M,w,text,pattern,compare)   File
>   "/Users/sayaneshome/Documents/plschk.py", line 95, in cost    if
>   text1[i]==patttern1[j]: NameError: global name 'patttern1' is not
>   defined

Comment: Would you please run your code through [PEP8 online](http://pep8online.com/) next time and fix all the errors before posting? The [results for your code](http://pep8online.com/s/yq7rGhb5) shows 22 errors after analyzing the function.

Comment: Okk..I will do that.

Comment: Hi,It was a part of code...as I couldn't paste the whole program here,so maybe that reasoned to error..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `patttern1` has three `t`'s. Remove one to get `pattern1`.

Comment: Thank you so much.I just noticed !!

Comment: @Borja *"Please, accept the answer as soon as you can"* is a little tacky - this is a trivial typo, and should be closed and deleted as such.